# Will my laptop emit less EMF with battery removed and plugged into wall with 3 prong plug. I use Ethernet with wired keypad and mouse

Tags: laptop, ethernet, battery, emf

Will my laptop emit less  or more EMF with battery removed and plugged into wall with 3 prong plug as opposed to just using the battery after it is charged and laptop is unplugged from wall. It is connected to Ethernet and I use a wired keypad and mouse. I wanted to just remove battery and use it like a desktop most of the time. The charging cord has a grounded 3 prong plug.

Comment: The difference is going to be so negligible that it honestly will not matter.

Comment: Wow thank you for such h a quick  response. I could not find info on this anywhere.

Comment: Why the concern about EMF, unless you're using it in a Farraday cage while making sensitive electrical measurements? If that is the case, then you probably need to enclose the laptop in its own cage, not plugged into anything but the experimental equipment, and with RF isolation on those connections.

Comment: I am trying to reduce as much emf levels as possible...in ways that are simple. I do sometimes have sensitivity issues with emf exposure.

Comment: While you can use a laptop without it's battery installed, it's not recommended, as the battery acts as a buffer against voltage/amperage spikes _(similar concept as the automotive 12v battery, which has the same purpose once the vehicle is started and running off the alternator)_.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people highly skeptical about EMF sensitivity (including me) - but the way to reduce EMF would be to reduce the amount of power drawn by the system.  Removing the battery would slightly decrease the power draw and thus the EMF field - but in return you would be at much greater risk of damaging your equipment (because the battery can act as a buffer against power fluctuations for a start).   The difference would also be negligible in reality.

You might want to clarify your post and advise what frequencies you believe you are sensitive to.  The characteristics of different frequency EMF fields are very different at different frequencies - and without this information any answer is, in reality, meaningless.

Comment: Appreciate your comments David. I don't have devices to measure frequencies.

Comment: Rereading my answer, it's wrong. You will have less EMF renning off battery if not plugged in ( no ac power = no EMF @ 50 hz on power side ). Of course you get more EMF when plugging in to charge because greater current draw.  I observe that if you don't know what frequency ranges/devices you are sensitive to you can't be suffering EMF sensitivity - you may be suffering from other issues tangenially related (like eye strain from using a screen to long, or other environmental factors)

Comment: >>  "I observe that if you don't know what frequency ranges/devices you are sensitive to you can't be suffering EMF sensitivity"  Hmm. Isn't that somewhat like suggesting that if I don't know exactly what bacteria has infected me, I can't be suffering from a bacterial infection?  (I have to admit, I'm skeptical about emf sensitivity as well)